# Is it possible to embed multiple ranges from a worksheet as .emf picture in Outlook mail body?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to embed multiple ranges from a worksheet as .emf pictures in outlook mail body. I have tried adjusting Ron de Bruin's code below that is shown for pasting the ranges as .jpg but this gives me the error "The image cannot currently be displayed".

Any help here would be appreciated. Please see Ron de Bruin's code below as shown on his website:

```
Sub Mail_small_Text_And_JPG_Range_Outlook()
    'Ron de Bruin, 25-10-2019
    'This macro use the function named : CopyRangeToJPG
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String
    Dim MakeJPG As String

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "Dear Customer" & "<br><br>" & _
        "Below you find a picture of your data." & "<br>" & _
        "If you need more information let me know." & "<br><br>" & _
        "Regards Ron<br>"
              
    'Create JPG file of the range
    'Only enter the Sheet name and the range address
    MakeJPG = CopyRangeToJPG("Sheet1", "A1:H50")

    If MakeJPG = "" Then
        MsgBox "Something go wrong, we can't create the mail"
        With Application
            .EnableEvents = True
            .ScreenUpdating = True
        End With
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "ron@debruin.nl"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .Attachments.Add MakeJPG, 1, 0
        'Note: Change the width and height as needed
        .HTMLBody = "<html><p>" & strbody & "</p><img src=""cid:NamePicture.jpg"" width=750 height=700></html>"
        .Display 'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub



Function CopyRangeToJPG(NameWorksheet As String, RangeAddress As String) As String
    'Ron de Bruin, 25-10-2019
    Dim PictureRange As Range

    With ActiveWorkbook
        On Error Resume Next
        .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).Activate
        Set PictureRange = .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).Range(RangeAddress)
        
        If PictureRange Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Sorry this is not a correct range"
            On Error GoTo 0
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        PictureRange.CopyPicture
        With .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).ChartObjects.Add(PictureRange.Left, PictureRange.Top, PictureRange.Width, PictureRange.Height)
            .Activate
            .Chart.Paste
            .Chart.Export Environ$("temp") & Application.PathSeparator & "NamePicture.jpg", "JPG"
        End With
        .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).ChartObjects(.Worksheets(NameWorksheet).ChartObjects.Count).Delete
    End With
    
    CopyRangeToJPG = Environ$("temp") & Application.PathSeparator & "NamePicture.jpg"
    Set PictureRange = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Why don't you start with .jpg images until you get the code working and sending those .jpg images. Then, adjust the code to handle .emf images.

Comment: Hi, I have managed to get the code working with the .jpg images but it no longer works when I adjust the code by changing all .jpg to .emf. Could there be something i'm missing when adjusting the code?